# Issue with gitbash to commit changes

Tags: commit, git-bash

I would like to commit some changes to GitHub from a local repository.
I can't commit the changes and then pushing it to the remote repository.

Could someone give me an advice?

[image: capure of my gitbash code]

Comment: Please include the code and errors as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "|" in the command.
It is pipe symbol and it is expecting another command in parallel.

Comment: harar@LAPTOP-15TQRNIJ MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projects/github-example (master)
$ git commit -m 'adds a python script that prints a message greeting Github'

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'harar@LAPTOP-15TQRNIJ.(none)')

Comment: you need to issue your github credentials before commit

Comment: git config --global user.email "your github email address"

Comment: git config --global user.name "Your username Name"

Comment: my answer is correct to the question you asked. Please select this as correct answer if you are okay with it

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that it is in good syntax.

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Above statement is the valid syntax to commit

```
git commit -m "add a python script that prints a message greeting |"
```

As Such above statement please make sure your commit message is enclosed with quotes